# How do I install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 on Lenovo M710?

Tags: 16.04, lenovo

I wrote a 64bit version of Ubuntu 16.04 to DVD.

Can I just boot and follow steps to install like on previous versions?

At present when I put in the DVD and boot, I just get a blank screen, and I'm not sure how to access the Lenovo BIOS. I tried F1 & F2.

Comment: have you tried Esc or F10 or 12?

Comment: If UEFI system, you want to boot Ubuntu installer in UEFI boot mode. While DVD should work, often better/easier to use flash drive. Do you have nVidia card/chip? If so you may need nomodeset. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo boot screen can be accessed by `Fn` + `F2` keys, boot device selection by `Fn` + `F12`.